# The same didSet block for several properties

Tags: ios, swift, properties

I have a class with several properties that work together as a group. `text`, `textColor`, `font`, etc...

I have a single method which then renders this depending on all three of these properties.

At the moment I have them defined...

```
var text: NSString = "DEFAULT TEXT" {
    didSet {
        updateText(text, baseFont: font)
    }
}
var font: UIFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(1) {
    didSet {
        updateText(text, baseFont: font)
    }
}
```

It doesn't feel right having the same block of code. (I have to do this twice more on other groups of parameters.

Any ideas of how I can tidy this up?

Hmm... just while typing I've been thinking of using a struct instead of three separate properties. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what's wrong with repeating the `updateText` call as the `didSet` observer of several properties. The bad smell here, if there is one, seems to me to be the way `updateText` is *declared*. If it's always going to use `self.text` and `self.font`, why not build that into its definition and give it no parameters? That way, you can write this much more neatly:

```
var text: NSString = "DEFAULT TEXT" {
    didSet { updateText() }
}
var font: UIFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(1) {
    didSet { updateText() }
}
```

Personally, I think that expresses very neatly (and DRYly) what you want to say: when any of these properties are updated, update the interface too.

Comment: Hmm... I guess you're right. I was putting the params in to make the functions more self contained. But I guess that defeats the object of having properties in the first place. lol

Comment: Exactly so! Properties = global visibility. If you have variations on this theme, declare multiple functions.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was overthinking my thinking :)